# Flink CEP state store

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

How does Flink CEP manage the intermittent states ? where does it store them ?
Is it just in-memory or is there a fast persistent storage backing the states ?

The documentation does not mention this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all stateful operations in Flink (e.g., windows, aggregations, SQL, timers, etc), Flink CEP uses [Flink's managed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/index.html). Where the working state is held, and where it is durably persisted, depends on which [state backend](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/state_backends.html) is being used. The RocksDB state backend allows for state larger than will fit into memory, and checkpoints are persisted in durable storage, such as HDFS, S3, or NFS.

Comment: Can this state be queried?

Comment: No, the state kept by Flink CEP cannot be queried.